# Nested divs with mixed height mode (% & px) Keep the '%' div fill out space not used by the 'px' div

Tags: html, css

I want the "blue" container to always be 70px high, while the previous "green" div always max out the height available when the div is resized with javascript.

I've played around with it for a while without finding a proper solution. Help will be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Does the parent div have a static height?

Comment: @Kyle Sevenoaks: Yes it does.

Comment: What should happen when the text in the (right, green, 100% height) div is too tall? Should there be a scrollbar? Or will it never be that tall?

Comment: @thirtydot : If the content in the green area is to large, I have a vertical scrollbar. With the solutions below, the bottom part of the scroller is hidden, with the the bottom part of the content, so I'm still looking for a solution for this.

Comment: I shall take a look in some minutes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As promised, here's my answer.

`absolute` inside `relative` positioning is the easiest way to do this.

[***Live Demo***](http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/nK6RY/)

**HTML:**

```
<div id="parent">
    <div id="left">height: 100%</div>
    <div id="right">Content</div>
    <div id="rightFooter">height: 70px</div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#parent {
    position: relative;
    height: 200px
}
#left, #right, #rightFooter {
    position: absolute
}
#left {
    width: 200px;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0
}
#right {
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 70px;
    left: 200px;
    overflow-y: auto
}
#rightFooter {
    height: 70px;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 200px
}
```

Comment: Awesome. Works perfectly. Thanks for taking the time :)

Answer (score 2):

Would something like this work?

***[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/loktar/KAtE3/2/)***

Added an animation of the height so you can see the content extending.

**Markup**

```
<div id="parent">
    <div class="left">
        Lefty
    </div>
    <div class="right">
        <div id="rightContent">
            right Content
        </div>
        <div id="rightFooter">
            Right Footer
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#parent{
    height:300px;
}
.left{
    float: left; 
    width: 33%; 
    background: red;
    height:100%;
}
.right{
    float : left; 
    width: 66%;
    height:100%;
}
#rightContent{
    height: 100%; 
    background: blue;
}
#rightFooter{
    background: yellow; 
    height: 70px; 
    float: right; 
    width: 100%; 
    margin-top: -70px;
}
.clear{
    clear:both;
}
```

Bah, before the comments come this is a partial solution, the text for the content area will bleed into the footer... looking at a solution for this, or someone else might be able to modify my markup/css to account for that.

Comment: I didn't copy you I swear! Came up with nearly an identical solution! :D +1

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/2hprD/ - It's not really a perfect solution, since as you can see in this fork of the original code, the scrollbar is hidden behind the bottom footer. I wonder if it's possible to build upon that code to perfect it ...

Answer (score 2):

Made an [example for you here](http://jsfiddle.net/Kyle_Sevenoaks/9PN3p/) :)

you need to have a left floated div for the left content and a wrapper for the two other right divs, also floated left.

Take a look :)

Comment: Nice :) you will have the same issue though, the content on the right will bleed into the footer. http://jsfiddle.net/loktar/9PN3p/1/ +1 for a good solution otherwise though.

Comment: Aye, only way I could think of doing it. Hopefully there won't be much content in the div :D